# Can you create a flexbox that will grow while another shrinks?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My current layout is as shown in the picture below:

[image: current layout]

A parent `div` containing two `div` `flex-box`'s set to `flex-direction: column;`. The left one is set to `flex-basis: initial;` and the right one is set to `flex: 1;`.

I want to know if I can edit the right `div`'s child elements using `flex-box` so that the bottom child element grows in height and the other shrinks when you widen the browser window as shown in the image below:

[image: layout on expanded browser]

So far, I've attempted to use

```
#pick_top {
    margin: 10px 10px 5px;
    flex: 0 1 270px;
    width: 100%;
}

#pick_bottom {
    margin: 5px 10px 10px;
    flex: 1 0 270px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But this didn't work, I assume because `shrink` is working on the height of the `div` shrinking rather than the width? Is this something I need media queries for?

Code below:

```css
.play_area {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 3;
  min-height: 540px;
}

.play_section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 215px;
  flex: initial;
}

.play_choice {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.choice_button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 170px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.choice_image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 110px;
}

.pick_section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 215px;
}

#pick_top {
  margin: 10px 10px 5px;
  flex: 0 1 270px;
  width: 100%;
}

#pick_bottom {
  margin: 5px 10px 10px;
  flex: 1 0 270px;
  width: 100%;
}

#my_play_image {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="play_area">
  <div class="play_section">
    <div class="play_choice">
      <div class="choice_button" id="button_a">
        <div class="choice_image">
          <img id="img_a" src="">
        </div>
        <p>X</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="play_choice">
      <div class="choice_button" id="button_b">
        <div class="choice_image">
          <img id="img_b" src="">
        </div>
        <p>X</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="play_choice">
      <div class="choice_button" id="button_c">
        <div class="choice_image">
          <img id="img_c" src="">
        </div>
        <p>X</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pick_section">
    <div class="pick" id="pick_top">
      <p class="pick">Your<br>pick</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pick" id="pick_bottom">
      <div id="my_play_image">
        <img src="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A flex item will only shrink if flex-shrink is set to a value other than 0 and the container doesn't have enough height/width. Also provide a working code snippet which would allow people to easily debug your code

Comment: Can you share the complete buildable code?

Comment: @Nitheesh what's the best platform to share code on? Sorry… new to this!

Comment: @Mr.Lupine you can share it here itself. Choose code snippet in the editor paste your html, css codes and post it.

Comment: Okay, I've added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RESULT**

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="top-left">Top</div>
      <div class="middle-left">Middle</div>
      <div class="bottom-left">Bottom</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="top-right">Top</div>
      <div class="bottom-right">Bottom</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can do it using `vw` units in your `flex-basis` bottom div.

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 3px solid gold;
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.top-left,
.middle-left,
.bottom-left {
  border: 2px solid red;

  flex-grow: 1;
}

.top-right,
.bottom-right {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.top-right {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.bottom-right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 50vw;
}
```

Comment: If the top right div will contain text then what's the point of all this ? text being inline will shrink if there's more width so all is need to have that layout is `flex:1` on the bottom right div. Or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

So, if my understanding is correct you want to change the height of the right-top-div based on the viewport width and you want your right-bottom-div to adjust accordingly.
Suppose you have your right-top-div and right-bottom-div wrapped inside your right-div-wrapper(which you have given flex:1). What you can do is:

```
.right-div-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.right-top-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(10vw) //Perform any calculations here
}

.right-bottom-div{
width: 100%;
flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Here what you have done is, you have assigned the height of the top div on the right side based on viewport width and rest of the area is occupied by the div at the bottom. If you want to have any specific width for the top div based on the viewport width you can make those calculations within the calc function for right-top-div.

Hope this answered your query.

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what I'm after. I don't want the right-top-div based on viewport width, I want it to fill the space allotted to it by the (on my original plan) orange div, that all works. The problem I'm having is I want the bottom right and top right divs to grow and shrink in height when the width is increased.